# Can I measure pinholes in a dielectric layer using LCR meter?

Tags: resistance, measurement, capacitance, voltage-measurement, leakage-current

I have a thin dielectric film (~1 um) and I want to measure the quality of the film in terms of not allowing leakage current through pinholes. Can I use an LCR meter for this purpose? If yes, how? If not, what would be some alternative, relatively inexpensive ways to test for it?

Comment: Probably the instrument you're looking for is a "megger".

Comment: The issue is that we have an LCR meter and a regular multimeter in our lab, so unless it's something that either of these two absolutely cannot do, I can't justify the purchase of a "megger" to my PI. Could you please tell me if an LCR meter can measure something like this, or is the megaohmmeter the only way out? P.S. I'm a Mechanical Engineer by trade so apologies if the questions are very fundamental.

Comment: You need enough voltage to cause current to flow through the (potential) pinholes. A typical LCR meter will not do this, and won't be as sensitive to the effect (somewhat lower resistance) anyway. A setup could be made with certain other equipment, but without knowing what's available to you, and without your being an EE, setting it up might be risky. A purpose-made instrument is the safest option. You can take this to whatever management or leadership you are responsive to.

Comment: a megger might well blow this very thin insulator into oblivion, especially if there are pinholes. It is designed to test breakdown voltage, not resistance. Probably a voltage of a few tens of volts, a high value resistor, and a voltmeter would do it (as proposed by the answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1\$\mu\$m of dielectric will probably have a breakdown in the **tens of volts**, so maybe just use an inexpensive multimeter in a high Ω range.

Most of them put a fraction of a volt or at most a few volts across the unknown resistance  (typically the diode test range puts the most voltage out). Enough to get a good reading, but not so much as to damage your insulation.

That should be good enough for relative quality measurements anyway. I assume you would use an electrolyte to make contact.

You can use the LCR meter in 'C' mode to get an estimate of the layer thickness, assuming you know the dielectric constant for your material (and assuming the leakage isn't too bad). If it's a good LCR meter then it may be able to get decent readings even in the presence of substantial leakage (they should display both capacitance and shunt resistance). Cheap ones, not so much.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thanks.
A follow-up question: if I know the dielectric constant, area and thickness of the material, I should be able to calculate a theoretical C value assuming it is a perfect dielectric. In reality, if it is not "ideal", due to charge leakage through pinholes, I am assuming I will get a different value of C, let's say C'. 
How does C' related to C (will it give the impedance reading, i.e. C' = Z), and is there a way I can calculate the resistance (either in series or parallel, I don't know how pinholes act) from the measured C' and theoretical C?

Comment: A good LCR meter, as I said, can separate leakage resistance a capacitance, but the series resistance has to be relatively low. See the manual for your LCR meter, compare [SRS](https://www.thinksrs.com/downloads/pdfs/manuals/SR715720m.pdf), for an example of an older, but relatively good, meter. Note you have pick the model.

Answer (score 1):

For detecting pinholes use an insulation tester.
for thick insulation a specialised drvice is needed, but
1 micron is fairly thin, you will need to decide on a suitable  test voltage and then test the insulation at that voltage.
if you have a power supply capable of sufficient voltage (maybe you need 20V - it depends on the material) you can test using a hand-held voltmeter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffsMhS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

`R1` mainly represents the internal resistance of the voltmeter instrument itself.